# FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

Command

```
df = pd.concat([df, df["XYZ"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Error

```
FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
```

XYZ is a column with Ordered Dictionary and trying to extract corresponding value for the key = Name
Command works fine, but raises a future warning.

Sample data -

| Id | XYZ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'XYZ'), ('url', 'somelink')])), ('Name', 'ABC')]) |
| 2 | OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'XYZ'), ('url', 'somelink')])), ('Name', 'PQR')]) |

Answer (score 1):

> Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.

You might implicitly inform what `dtype` should be used by `pd.Series` following way

```
import functools
import pandas as pd
Float64Series = functools.partial(pd.Series,dtype="float64")
s = Float64Series([1,2,3,4,5])  # these would be turned into int64 if you would use pd.Series
print(s)
```

gives output

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Observe `.0`s and that `dtype` is `float64`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pd.json_normalize`:

```
out = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(df['XYZ'])], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
   Id                                                XYZ Name attributes.type attributes.url
0   1  {'attributes': {'type': 'XYZ', 'url': 'somelin...  ABC             XYZ       somelink
1   2  {'attributes': {'type': 'XYZ', 'url': 'somelin...  PQR             XYZ       somelink
2   3  {'attributes': {'type': 'XYZ', 'url': 'somelin...  RST             XYZ       somelink
3   4  {'attributes': {'type': 'XYZ', 'url': 'somelin...  DEF             XYZ       somelink
```